# ng: command not found despite installing @angular/cli

Tags: command-line, angular-cli, npm-install

After a few days of using @angular/cli, ng suddenly was no longer accessible. I didn't touch anything to make this happen.

So far I've tried:

1. uninstalling and reinstalling @angular/cli

   after installing globally, the @angular/cli 
   nor the ng are neither in my /Users//.npm-global
   or my /Users//.npm-global directories.
2. setting and resetting the $PATH (below)

   /Users//.npm-global/bin:/Users//.npm-packages/bin:
3. added ~/.npm-global to my /etc/paths file

But I still have no success in accessing the ng command anymore. This is really frustrating. Why does my computer no longer recognize something it was just using a day ago without being provoked? And how can I fix this? This isn't the first time this has happened.

npm version: 6.14.4

node version: v.14.0.0

macOS Catalina: 10.15.4